# SeleneseTestCase is deprecated - how to call verify* methods?

Tags: java, selenium

When I use the code generated by the JUnit 4 formatter in the Selenium IDE, I get warnings that the class SeleneseTestCase is deprecated - makes sense since it's supposed to b JUnit 4 syntax and use annotations instead of deriving from a test class.

The issue is when I modify my code to not extend SeleneseTestCase I'm not sure how to call the verify* methods - they appear to only exist in the deprecated class.  I can run my selenium actions using the code below but verifyTrue is undefined.  What is the correct way to call the verify methods in Selenium 2.0b2?

```
private static Selenium selenium;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://testurl.com/");
    selenium.start();
}

@Test
public void testLogin() throws Exception {
    selenium.open("/test.html");
    verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Please Sign In"));
    .....
```

Comment: This post shows the correct JUnit4 format of the Selenium Java test cases but it doesn't show how to verify text http://qtp-help.blogspot.com/2009/05/junit-4.html

Comment: Don't declare your `Selenium` `static`!

Comment: Oops - thanks - playing around with code too much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the idea is for you to use JUnit's `Assert.assertXXX()` the difference is that `verifyXXX` will fail during teardown instead of immediately but I think with Selenium tests you usually want to fail as fast as possible (since those tests tend to be slow).

Comment: So the whole idea of verify is going away in version 2?

Comment: Sounds like it. All in all I recommend you take a look at the WebDriver API of Selenium, it is way better and has really good integration with the actual Browser.

Answer (score 1):

As SeleneseTestCase is deprecated, you can use SeleneseTestBase instead of SeleneseTestCase. The java code for this as below:

```
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleneseTestBase;
public class MySeleniumTest extends SeleneseTestBase{

@Test
public void aMethod(){
verifyTrue(boolean condition);
}
}
```

If you don't extends SeleneseTestBase class you can use an object as below:

```
new SeleneseTestBase().verifyTrue(boolean condition);
```

Comment: More specifically your code would be: verifyTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Please Sign In"));